# Efficient way to map two text files into one based on a column

Tags: java, python, linux, shell

I have two text files:

File 1:

```
Category ID

C1  A1
C2  A2
C3  A3  
C1  A4
C4  A5
```

File 2:

```
Purchase ID

O1  A1
O1  A2
O1  A3
O1  A4
O2  A5
O2  A6
O3  A7
O3  A2
```

I need to create a File 3:

```
O1 A1 C1
O1 A2 C2
```

and so on.

The File 1 and File 2 will be extremely large.

Can some one recommend an efficient way of doing this (instead of searching one by one from file 1 and file 2), probably in python.

But other languages are also okay. Even excel is good, if that can be used?

Any leads on any kind of solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `join` in a shell:

```
join -j 2 -o 2.1 2.2 1.1 File1 File2
```

- `-j 2` means "join on the 2nd column"
- `-o` specifies the order of the columns in the output, `2.1` stands for "file 2, column 1"

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk` command to combine these 2 files:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{id[$2]=$1; next} {print $0, id[$2]}' file1 file2

Purchase ID Category
O1  A1 C1
O1  A2 C2
O1  A3 C3
O1  A4 C1
O2  A5 C4
O2  A6
O3  A7
O3  A2 C2
```

Answer (score 0):

Import 2 files to 2 tables in a database (e.g. SQLite), and then select from T1 join T2 on T1.id=T2.id.

The sqlite shell can set csv or tabs mode. (Comma/Tab separated.) Use `.import` and `.once` for input and output.